Facing the below error while upgrading from Sprinboot 3.2.12 to 3.4.0- NoSuchMethod CollectionUtils.newLinkedHashSet(int)'
Facing the below error while upgrading from Sprinboot 3.2.12 to 3.4.0
Spring framework version upgraded from 6.1.15 to 6.2.1
NoSuchMethod 'java.util.LinkedHashSet org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.newLinkedHashSet(int)'
How can this be resolved?
checked the dependency tree and verified that all spring versions are compatible

Please include the relevant POM configuration code.

make sure spring-boot-starter is in sync with the newly added dependencies.
try using dependencymanagement in pom.xml to make sure version is consistent.

sprint-test version used is 6.2.1
Junit-Jupiter version 5.11.3
